# why the title of a viewcontroller is not centered even though I use a simple (self.title = "title")

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

as you can see, the title of a view is offset to the right a bit,
90% of the screens don't show this behavior...

[image: misaligned title]

this is the code in `AppDelegate.swift`

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 13)!,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()
]
```

and this is how I change the title

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    self.title = "Hearts"
}
```

any hints?

Comment: share your storyboard or xib view controller.

Comment: Your code (that you have added to your answer) should not affect the text position, there must be something else that is misplacing the text.

Comment: I embed the view controller in a navigation controller programmatically, not using storyboards, and there's nothing special about them.

Comment: You should call `super.viewWillAppear(animated: animated)`, you are missing it.

Answer (score 0):

I left a silly line in viewDidLoad that caused this

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
```

this is weird, **but that solved it.**

Comment: As I said, your code was looking good, something else was disturbing it :)